# How Can I Fix This "react-native-gesture-handler" error?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNGestureHandlerRootView" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:
in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by Browser)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by Browser)
in Browser (created by Home)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Home)
in Home (created by Manager)
in Manager (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View
in SafeAreaView (created by App)
in Provider (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer

I Already Tried These Options:
1/import "react-native-gesture-handler"; both in App.js or AppEntry.js
2/Deleted the node_modules folder an run npm i
Please I am stuck here!

Comment: Try going into /ios and running `pod install`

Comment: @Dominic even though i am using developing with expo on android virtual device?

Comment: Ah then I guess not (I'm not experienced with expo but thought it should be all automatic)